# InvalidOperationException when I try to delete an image manually from RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, image, richtextbox

I am trying to create an app where I can enter text and images into a RichTextBox, serialize it, then deserialize it and load it back to a RichTextBox so that I can change it later. When I load the images from the serialized xml file, everything displays correctly, but when I try to delete the image from the RichTextBox manually by pressing backspace, I get the following exception: Cannot serialize a non-public type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode'.

Here's how I extract and store the data from the RichTextBox. It checks all the blocks, and if it finds an image then it just saves a placeholder string there in the List text so that when it goes back it'll know to put the image back at that location:

```
public void GetFindingsData(FlowDocument flowDoc, List<string> text, List<byte[]> bytes)
    {
        foreach (Block block in flowDoc.Blocks)
        {
            if (block.GetType() == typeof(Paragraph))
            {
                foreach (Run run in ((Paragraph)block).Inlines)
                {
                    text.Add(run.Text);
                }
            }

            else if (block.GetType() == typeof(BlockUIContainer) && ((BlockUIContainer)block).Child.GetType() == typeof(Image))
            {
                Image img = (Image)((BlockUIContainer)block).Child;
                bytes.Add(Storage.ImageToByteArray(img));
                text.Add("imageplaceholder_" + (bytes.Count - 1).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's how I put that data back into a FlowDocument for display in a RichTextBox:

```
public FlowDocument createFlowDocument(List<string> runs, List<byte[]> bytes)
    {
        FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string run in runs)
        {
            if (run == "imageplaceholder_" + counter.ToString())
            {
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(Storage.ByteArrayToImage(bytes[counter])));
                counter++;
            }

            else
            {
                Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
                par.Inlines.Add(run);
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(par);
            }
        }

        return flowDoc;
    }
```

In case you need it, here's how I serialize the data from the RichTextBox. All my other data is serialized to xml, but that doesn't work for images so I first serialize it to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
    {
        byte[] imageBuffer = null;

        if (image != null)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image.Source as BitmapSource));
                encoder.Save(stream);
                imageBuffer = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return imageBuffer;
    }
```

This is where I serialize and deserialize everything to/from an xml file (although I don't think the problem is here):

```
public static void SaveData(StoredData data)
    {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StoredData));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(readerString, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
            }
    }

public static StoredData LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            StoredData storedData = new StoredData();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(readerString, FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StoredData));
                storedData = (StoredData)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            return storedData;

        }

        catch
        {
            StoredData newData = new StoredData();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (StoredData));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(readerString, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, newData);
            }

            return newData;
        }
    }
```

And here's how I get the image back from the byte array:

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImage(Byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

            BitmapFrame frame = decoder.Frames.First();

            frame.Freeze();
            Image newImage = new Image();
            newImage.Source = frame;
            return newImage;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you see that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820098/c-sharp-wpf-convert-bitmapimage-pasted-in-richtextbox-to-binary)? It seems similar to your problem.

Comment: I did, and please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seemed like they only had the same issue I did transiently, before deciding on a different approach that circumvented the problem. In case I didn't underline my problem well enough, I have no issues saving from or loading to the RichTextBox. It's ONLY when I try to delete the reloaded picture that I run into this error. Even deleting reloaded text works fine.

Comment: Yes I got it. So, when you get that exception? On which line? What do you do in your RichTextBox's text changed event?

Comment: It occurs in PresentationFramework.dll. Should I post the entire StackTrace? And I don't do anything in the RichTextBox's text changed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user deletes the image from a `RichTextBox`, it [copies](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit.cs,e695f0260acc17db,references) the deleted items to the undo stream by serializing them to XAML.  This is evident from the stack trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.VerifyTypeIsSerializable(Type type)
   at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.WriteItem(MarkupObject item, Scope scope)
   at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.WriteItem(MarkupObject item, Scope scope)
   at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.WriteItem(MarkupObject item)
   at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.SaveAsXml(XmlWriter writer, MarkupObject item)
   at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.SaveAsXml(XmlWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(Object obj, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(Object obj)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit.CopyObjectNode(TextTreeObjectNode objectNode, ContentContainer& container)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit.CopyContent(TextTreeNode node, TextTreeNode haltNode)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeDeleteContentUndoUnit..ctor(TextContainer tree, TextPointer start, TextPointer end)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextTreeUndo.CreateDeleteContentUndoUnit(TextContainer tree, TextPointer start, TextPointer end)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextContainer.DeleteContentInternal(TextPointer startPosition, TextPointer endPosition)
```

This causes a problem for you, because the type [`BitmapFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is *abstract*, and the type actually returned by `BitmapDecoder.Frames.First()`, [`BitmapFrameDecode`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/BitmapFrameDecode.cs), is *internal*, and thus [can't be serialized to XAML](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/Primitives/MarkupWriter.cs,463).

However, I don't see why you need to use `BitmapDecoder`.  Why not just use a regular [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  If I load your image using the following code, the inserted image can now be deleted:

```
    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(Byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        {
            var frame = new BitmapImage();
            frame.BeginInit();
            frame.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            frame.StreamSource = stream;
            frame.EndInit();
            frame.Freeze();
            Image newImage = new Image() { Source = frame };
            return newImage;
        }
    }
```

Well, having done this, I found a secondary problem: if I tried to undo deleting the image after deleting it, it wouldn't come back.  Instead, a junk `BlockUIContainer` with an empty image would be restored.  I was unable to determine exactly why this happened, but it had something to do with the fact that the [`BitmapImage.BaseUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.baseuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was null when the `BitmapImage` was created from a memory stream rather than from a [`UriSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I was able to work around this, in turn, by serializing to a temporary [`XamlPackage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataformats.xamlpackage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    public static void AddBlockUIContainerImage(this FlowDocument doc, byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        var image2 = Storage.ByteArrayToImage(imageBytes);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var subDoc = new FlowDocument();
            subDoc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(image2));
            new TextRange(subDoc.ContentStart, subDoc.ContentEnd).Save(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage, true);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var target = new TextRange(doc.ContentEnd, doc.ContentEnd);
            target.Load(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        }
    }
```

Having done this, the `BaseUri` was no longer null; undo, redo, delete, undo delete, and redo delete all worked.

Since this workaround means you are effectively deserializing the image twice, you might want to consider storing each image as a `XamlPackage` encoded byte array rather than a `Png`-encoded byte array.

Comment: Works like a charm, I can't thank you enough! A problem I had in looking for an answer was that I didn't know what happens when you delete something from a textbox in WPF by pressing the backspace key, and I wasn't sure what to look for to find out. Searching with the term "delete" tended to give answers about programmatically deleting, while "backspace" gave a lot of answers about  catching and changing the backspace event (while I wanted to know what happens by default). Is there a resource that covers what happens behind the scenes for textbox events like copying, deleting, etc.?

Comment: @mrmry - I don't know of any good resource for understanding how `RichTextBox` and `FlowDocument` work.  Even the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/FlowDocument.cs) is unhelpful since a lot of the work is done in child elements or helper classes.   If one is trying to see the structure of a `FlowDocument`, I find dumping to XAML helps.